# Problema Swift con Webservice

Tags: webservice, ios, swift, xcode

Hola buenas estoy haciendo una app sencilla para aprender a usar *WebService* pero tengo un problema.

En la línea donde inicializo `task` me da el siguiente error cuando lo ejecuto y le doy al botón para que llame al *service*.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func llamadaWebService(){

        let urlPath = "http://api.openweatherapp.rg/data/2.5/weather?q=\(String(describing: captura.text))"

        let url = URL(string: urlPath)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil) {

                //Imprime error si no está vacío . Si hay error es que hubo error en la conexión

                print("error")
            }

            let nsdata:NSData = NSData(data: data!)

            print(nsdata)

        //    self.recuperarClimaDeJson(nsdata)
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar tu url esta mal intente con esta y me funciono : "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=phoenix".

Te recomiendo usar opcionales en lugar de forzar el unwrap (Usar una variable cuando no sabes si tiene un valor o es nula).

Probablemente nsdata sea la causa del error (Por cierto no necesitas convertir de Data a NSData). Este nula por eso te da ese error cuando quieres imprimir.

Te recomiendo leer un poco de Swift 4.

Por ultimo debes agregar a tu archivo info.plist el key NSAppTransportSecurity para permitir la conexión a http; click derecho-open as-source code. y dentro del primer dic que aparece pega esto (Esta no es la mejor manera de hacerlo pero es la mas rápida):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Aquí un ejemplo que no va a mandar ningún error de código pero tampoco va hacer la consulta ya que yo no tengo un Key para la API, también se convierte el objeto data a un dictionary(También no es la mejor manera, para esto lee un poco de Codable, Encodable y Decodable):

```
func task() {
    let captura = "phoenix"
        let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(String(describing: captura))"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else{
        print("URL invalida")

        return
    }

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error{
                print("ERROR: \(error)")
            }

            guard let unwrappedData = data else{
                 print("Datos vacios algo salio mal")
                return
            }

            do{

                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: []) as? [String: Any] else{
                    print("Error en el json")
                    return
                }

                print(json)


            }catch{
                print("No se pudo convertir el objeto a un Diccionario")
            }



            //    self.recuperarClimaDeJson(nsdata)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```